# How to execute another action after generated by ajax with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have [this ajax function](http://pastie.org/798788) with jquery. (http://pastie.org/798788)

The outputs is the following.

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Latest Messages or Task To Do</h1>

    <ul style="display: block;" id="message_ul">
    <li class="86">
<div class="listbox"><span class="user">
<strong>Administrator</strong></span>
<span class="date">2010-01-28 08:57:43</span>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_backendpro2/index.php/messages/admin/changestatus/86"
class="todo">to do</a>
<span class="msg">Change links in message, to do, completed 
and delete to anchor </span>
</div>
   </li>

<li class="85">
<div class="listbox"><span class="user">
<strong>Administrator</strong></span>
<span class="date">2010-01-28 08:51:15</span>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_backendpro2/index.php/messages/admin/changestatus/85"
class="todo">to do</a>
<span class="msg"> meta tag keywords and 
description should show from page input/database </span>
</div>
</li>

<li class="84">
...
...
```

Now I am trying to add another ajax with class="todo". However when I tried this for testing. It does not alert. It executes the php function.

```
$(".todo").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hei");

});
```

I am not sure why. Is it because it is created by ajax?

Is it something to do with binding? How can I make it work?

I am using CodeIgniter.

Other [php functions are here](http://pastie.org/798802). [(http://pastie.org/798802)](http://pastie.org/798802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to be using the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn)-style event binding **and** name the event object as a parameter to the click handler.

```
$(".todo").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) event:

```
$(".todo").live('click', function() { // <- Extend the "click" event to every .todo element created in the future
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hei");
});
```

Comment: It still does not alert. It executes php.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand how everything is going on.  But if you're inserting the links with class 'todo' after you've executed the 'bind' function, you either need to:
a)  Re-call the bind function (first unbinding).
b)  Use the jquery live function so you automatically attach to any new 'todo' classes.